# How do I make ajax interact with a database in order to post, get, and delete?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

How do I use ajax to post/delete/get to and from a database?

I want to be able to post and be able to delete whatever I post to this link:

http://www.bmoseley.com/ajax/listrecords.php

(this is an assignment)

however, I have to use /ajax/addrecord.php and /ajax/deleterecord.php in order to be able to add and delete posts to /ajax/lisrecords.php

Let me state this: I don't want you to assume that you're doing an assignment for me, I want someone to explain how wrong I am with my code and understanding of ajax and what ajax script I can use in order to accomplish my goal.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 function validateForm ()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"] ["fullname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
    {
    alert ("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
}

    function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var e = evt || window.event; //window.event is safer,
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;                        
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 47 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
    if (e.shiftKey) return false;
    return true;
}
</script>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="info">
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get" action="http://www.bmoseley.com/ajax/listrecords.php">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td><input class="fullname" maxlength="50" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="phonenumber" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" placeholder="Phone Number"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
<div id="displayInfo">
<script>
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
data: JSON.stringify(foo),
url: "http://www.bmoseley.com/ajax/listrecords.php",
success: function(data){console.log(data);}, 
failure: function(e){console.log('ERROR: ' + e)}
});
</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So till how much have u tried..??

Comment: @techfoobar: The server actually specifies  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Comment: You wrote `JSON.stringify(foo)`, but it doesn't seem you have `foo` defined anywhere. The code will throw a `ReferenceError` and not run at all.

Comment: Oh, dammit. @FelixKling Kling you're right, but since I don't know much. I have an input field for fullname and phonenumber, what would you suggest changing in the ajax code?

Comment: @FelixKling - Ahh. Ok. Didn't check that prior to commenting. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your form is directly sending to your php-file, you must prevent it to submit to your php, but to send via your ajax request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
         function validateForm () {
             var x=document.forms["myForm"] ["fullname"].value;
            if (x==null || x=="")
            {
                alert ("First name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
        }

        function isNumberKey(evt) {
            var e = evt || window.event; //window.event is safer,
            var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 47 || charCode > 57))
                return false;
            if (e.shiftKey) return false;
            return true;
        }
        </script>
     </head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="info">
                <form id="myForm" method="get" action="/ajax/listrecords.php">
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input class="fullname" maxlength="50" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Name</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input class="phonenumber" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" placeholder="Phone Number"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
                <div id="displayInfo">
                </div>
                <script>
                        //loaded when dom is ready
                        $(function() {
                            var frm = $('#myForm');
                            //submit is nearly the same as onsubmit in your html before
                            frm.submit(function (ev) {
                                //preventDefault prevents the form to submit normally, because you dont want this, you want ajax!
                                ev.preventDefault();

                                //validating your form
                                if(validateForm())
                                {
                                    //if valide make the request
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: frm.attr('method'),
                                        url: frm.attr('action'),
                                        data: frm.serialize(),
                                        success: function (data) {
                                            alert('ok');
                                            //or when data is only a string you could add it to your div
                                            $('#displayInfo').html(data);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                            });
                        });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

in the ajax-jquery-docs you will find more examples.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure because these are new terms to me, what I'm trying to do is be able to use the form to add the name and phone number to the listrecords.php file my professor created. As he also created addrecord.php and deleterecord.php to add and delete the phone numbers. He stated to deal with these 3 php files in order to manipulate them with ajax. So I may be doing something completely wrong with not using addrecord and deleterecord at all.

Comment: i have edited my post with a full example, could you pls add your directory structure, because i dont know where your files are and where your html is called from

Comment: Sorry, I fell asleep. If you mean my directory in the FTP client it's /public_html/records/index.html or if you meant my website estebanrodriguez.durb.co/records/ Hope that helps.